# Simplifying A'B+A'D'+BD

Tags: boolean

I'm having trouble simplifying this Boolean expression: A'B+A'D'+BD (ie., Not A and B or Not A and Not D or B and D).

Using K-maps, I know it is supposed to simplify to A'D'+BD.  Using an online Boolean evaluator has also verified this.  However, I can't seem to get it using Boolean identities.  I'm sure once I see it, it will be obvious but right now, I'm just stuck.  Any ideas?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a step by step deduction from A'B + A'D' + BD to A'D' + BD.

```
A'B + A'D' + BD                   // original expression
=== A'B1 + A'D' + BD              // 1 (true) is identity element
=== A'B(D+D') + A'D' + BD         // D+D' is true
=== (A'BD + A'BD') + A'D' + BD    // distribution
=== A'BD + A'BD' + A'D' + BD      // association
=== A'D' + A'BD' + BD + A'BD      // commutation
=== A'D' + A'D'B + BD + BDA'      // commutation
=== (A'D' + A'D'B) + (BD + BDA')  // association
=== A'D' + BD                     // absorption (2x)
```